# F# types with units of measure vs System.Math

Tags: generics, f#, units-of-measurement

I defined my own unit of measure to represent radians:

```
[<Measure>]
type rad
```

Then I realized that having a value e.g. of type `float<rad>` I can't use many of the functions defined in System.Math (as they work with 'plain' floats)

```
let valueWithUnit = 5.45<rad>
let absValue = Math.Abs valueWithUnit // <--- error!!
```

I created a naive piece of code that allows functions to handle `float<rad>` values as well:

```
let liftToRadFunc (f : float -> float) (arg : float<rad>) =
    arg * 1.</rad>
    |> f
    |> (*) 1.<rad>

let result = (liftToRadFunc Math.Abs) valueWithUnit // <--- now works fine
```

but the problem with it is that it's totally non-generic. Assuming I'd like to introduce an unit to represent degrees as well - what then ? Would I need to copy the code and change all the units from "rad" to "deg" ? Or maybe there's a better solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [core operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754.aspx) of F# are mostly unit-of-measure aware. For example, `abs` works with units of measure and renders `System.Math.Abs` redundant.

It is possible to generalize the function from the question in terms of the units used:

```
let liftToKeepUnits f (arg : float<'u>) : float<'u> =
    float arg |> f |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure
```

Though this simply keeps the units, which is only correct if the function has no effect on the units. So I'd use this lifting function to create specific, unit-aware functions, rather than lifting functions where they are used.

In my experience, the most useful tool is the ability to make types and functions generic in terms of units of measure. Type inference will not always do this on its own, but adding unit-of-measure type annotations will often do the trick. In more complicated cases, `LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure` and `LanguagePrimitives.Float32WithMeasure` allow, together with a type annotation, to add units where one would otherwise run into the constraint that forbids non-zero values with generic unit-of-measure arguments.

Also, types can have unit-of-measure arguments like this:

```
type MyType<[<Measure>] 'u> ...
```

When using all of these features, functions that aren't aware of units become the exception, and it's not a big problem to manually add or remove units in the remaining cases.